# Adding integers that are imported from a text file

Tags: java, import

I am a first time Java student and I have a project where I ask the user for a file path to a text file. The text file loads and in this case it imports information about tenants (renters) that includes first name, last name, unit #, amount of rent, etc. After it is imported I am supposed to add up the rent for all the tenants and display the average amount of rent paid. I have everything working but I am unable to add up the rent from the text file and display the average. Help Please!

Here is my main class that does all the work

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {

    public Program(){
        Tenants t = new Tenants();
        System.out.print("What is the path of the address file?");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName = s.next();
        HashMap<String, AddressEntry> addressMap = new HashMap<String, AddressEntry>();

        File addressData = new File(fileName);
        try{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(addressData);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        //Call the constructor inside of Tenants class and displays average
        t.Average();

        String line = null;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            String [] entryData = line.split(",");
            AddressEntry a = new AddressEntry();
            a.firstName = entryData[0];
            a.lastName = entryData[1];
            a.unitNumber = entryData[2];
            a.bedRoomQty = Integer.parseInt(entryData[3]);
            a.bathRoomQty = Integer.parseInt(entryData[4]);
            a.rent = Integer.parseInt(entryData[5]);
            addressMap.put(a.firstName, a);
        }
        br.close();

        }catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
             System.out.println("There was an error in loading the addresses");
             fnfe.printStackTrace();
         }catch(IOException ioe){
             System.out.println("There was an error in loading the addresses");
             ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        boolean askQuestion = true;

         while(askQuestion){
            System.out.println("Who would you like information about? \n");
            System.out.println("Names: ");
            for(Map.Entry<String, AddressEntry> a : addressMap.entrySet()){
                System.out.println(a.getKey() );

            }
            String userAnswer = s.next();

            if(userAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("X")){
                askQuestion = false;
                System.out.println("Goodbye...");
            }else{
                if(addressMap.containsKey(userAnswer)){
                System.out.println(addressMap.get(userAnswer));
                }else{
                    System.out.println("That address name does not exist.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code just for the address entry

```
public class AddressEntry {

        public String firstName = "NONE";
        public String lastName = "NONE";
        public String unitNumber = "NONE";
        public int bedRoomQty = 0;
        public int bathRoomQty = 0;
        public int rent = 0;

    public String toString(){
        return "First name: " + firstName + "\n"
                + "Last Name: " + lastName + "\n"
                + "Unit Number: " + unitNumber + "\n"
                + "Bedroom QTY: " + bedRoomQty + "\n"
                + "Bathroom QTY: " + bathRoomQty + "\n"
            + "Rent: $" + rent+ "\n";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to programming, i suggest that you start by desining the procces and when you are done start programming...

passing this block

```
String line = null;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            String [] entryData = line.split(",");
            AddressEntry a = new AddressEntry();
            a.firstName = entryData[0];
            a.lastName = entryData[1];
            a.unitNumber = entryData[2];
            a.bedRoomQty = Integer.parseInt(entryData[3]);
            a.bathRoomQty = Integer.parseInt(entryData[4]);
            a.rent = Integer.parseInt(entryData[5]);
            addressMap.put(a.firstName, a);
        }
        br.close();
```

all tenants information should be loaded in addressMap. So, at this point you should iterate over addressMap and start adding up the rent...

```
double total = 0.0;
double sum = 0.0;
for(Entry<String, AdressEntry> entry : addressMap.entrySet())
{
   total++;
   sum = sum + entry.getValue().rent;

}
double average = sum / total;
```

so, the procces is:

1. read the file and recover info of tenants.
2. calculate average rent.

bye!